# How to fix api/auth/error issue of next-auth

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to learn nextjs and wanted to try next-auth.
When I open any pages protected(I am opening /features) by next-auth I am getting redirected to /api/auth/error?error=Configuration. I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. All other Stackoverflow answers say I should add a secret key but I already did that.
Here is the middleware.js

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config ={matcher:["/features"]};
```

[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { options } from "./options";

export default NextAuth(options);
```

options.js

```
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const options = {
    providers: [
      GithubProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
      }),
      DiscordProvider({
        clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      }),
      CredentialsProvider({
        name: "Credentials",
        credentials: {
          username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "awesome-username" },
          password: { label: "Password", type: "password",placeholder:"your password" },
        },
        async authorize(credentials) {
          const user = { id: 1, name: "vaibhav", password: "next" };
          //   const res = await fetch("/your/endpoint", {
          //     method: 'POST',
          //     body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
          //     headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
          //   })
          //   const user = await res.json()
          if (
            credentials?.username === user.name &&
            credentials.password === user.password
          )
            return user;
          return null;
        },
      }),
    ],
    secret: process.env.NEXT_AUTH_SECRET,
  };
```

I tried to open the `/features` page after logging in but I am getting redirected to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error?error=Configuration